# Cannot Upload Excel file in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to upload excel file many times in CodeIgniter, but not successfully

(The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.)

Controller Coding:

```
                $this->load->library('upload');
                $this->load->helper('file');
                //$config['upload_path'] = XLS_PATH;
                $config['upload_path'] = './public/test/files/test/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'xls|xlsx';
                $config['max_size'] = 0;

                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                echo $this->upload->file_type;

                if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
                {

                    echo $this->upload->display_errors();

                }
                else
                {
                      $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');

                }
```

Views:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="userfile" name="userfile"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="sumit" value="Test" />
 </form>
```

Comment: what's the limit in your php.ini file?

Comment: upload_max_filesize = 2M

Comment: does your excel file size exceed 2M?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is bug in that library maybe [this](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/204725/) will help